# How to run an i386 .so library on an armhf system?

Tags: linker, arm, shared-libraries, cross-compiling, qemu

I need to implement a system with a third party device using a Raspberry Pi.

The device is connected using USB, and the manufacturer has provided a few software implementation demos, and the driver library includes a C++ header file and a C shared object file compiled for i386.

I need to be able to run this driver library on the RPi. My idea is to build a C++ program I can use to get the data from the device, compile for i386, and run it with `qemu-i386`. I have tried to execute this idea, but have run into some problems relating to the linking, like the executable looking for `ld-linux.so.2`, which my RPi doesn't have.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: @PeterSmith Do you mind accepting my answer if it helped you out?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea to run it for QEMU, instead install box86, [link](https://box86.org), it'll automatically take over when it detects a 32bit x86 executable and should work great for your use case